# How to prevent cross site scripting in Summernote in form in Laravel5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, controller, xss

I have done the scripting for other input methods using the `strip_tags` method, but it does not apply for Summernote.

Can I prevent Cross Site Scripting using `script_tags` or any other methods?

I've already tried using the `strip_tags` method and it did not work.

```
$a['description'] = strip_tags($data['description']); //In the Controller
```

```
<textarea id='summernote' name="description">//In the form
```

I want the code to be saved in database without using the script tags only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "e" function like this:

```
$a['description'] = e($data['description']);
```

Comment: could you please elaborate the use of this function

Comment: it is like PHP's htmlentities() function.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** You can still introduce a cross-site scripting vulnerability even without the script tag. For example, copy and paste this from an html page into summernote. Mousing over the button will make the user navigate to the specified page, with no script tag.

```
<button style="h1" onmouseover='window.location = "http://www.google.com";'>
    Totally not malicious. Nothing bad will happen if you just mouseover this text.
</button>
```